# Simultaneous GraphicsDevice's in different threads

Tags: c#, xna

I have an XNA application that renders onto a second monitor (adaptor 1), at regular intervals it takes a screenshot of itself and stores it as a Texture2D.

As this application launches it also shows a Windows Form with a panel. This panel is supposed to be drawn on by a seperate GraphicsDevice, and displays the Texture2D.

The problem I am having is that as I run this code in the Windows form to create the GraphicsDevice:

```
mainDevice = new GraphicsDevice(GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter, DeviceType.Hardware, panel1.Handle, pp);
```

I get a DeviceLostException. The standard advice in this case is to catch the exception, sleep the thread for a few seconds and retry, but this just puts me in an infinite loop.

I suspect this is because my XNA class is using the hardware at the same time and that I am thinking about this the wrong way. But I can't find any documentation on how I should be doing this correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphicsDevice is a physical device, not something attached to a window.  If you have two physical devices, you can instantiate another GraphicsDevice using a different GraphicsAdapter (meaning not the default).

If you're not going to put much load on the device, or if one of them does not need a lot of hardware acceleration, you can create a software device instead.  The capabilities may be similar, but it's going to be a lot slower.

Other than that, the only things I can think of are to see if XNA supports command buffers (which I'm not sure it does) and manage locking / unlocking the device yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not wrong, you are trying to draw on two different monitors at the same time, with two different applications (or, better put, two different GraphicsDevice objects).

Lets look things correctly first.

Physically you have a Videocard and a Monitor. Of course, most video interacting platforms like DirectX, OpenGL, XNA, etc. perform primarily on and with the videocard, not the processor, right?

Now, in programming-based conception, we have the GraphicsDevice class, and the GraphicsAdapter class. Rings a bell right?

Although there is not an exact correlation between the GraphicsDevice and the Videocart, and the GraphicsAdapter and a monitor, there is a very close relationships between these objects.

The GraphicsDevice does not actually represent a Videocard (although Jeff put that in a very simple way to make it understandable). A GraphicsDevice object is an INTERACTOR with the Videocard. Analogously, we could think the GraphicsDevice object is a painting instructor that indicates the paintor (videocard) where and what to paint. It is designed to command on how to fulfill these tasks.

The GraphicsAdapter has a relationship a little closer to the monitor, so we are going to see it as the canvas in our analogy.

Now let's see. Imagine our paintor has as many arms as GraphicsAdapters the Videocard supports. This means it can paint as much canvas at the same time.

Programmatically, we can instantiate as many GraphicsDevice as we want both for a paintor and its canvases. Each instructor can tell the paintor to paint a different thing on a different canvas. But wouldn't the paintor be a little confused if two instructors told him to draw different things on a same canvas?

Of course it would. A paintor can only perform a painting instruction on a canvas at a time (looking at it very superficially, of course, but enough to understand the concept). That is why you cannot instantiate and access two graphics device on a same adapter. Whenever the adapter changes its graphics device (instructor), the other instructor is "lost". Meaning, he is not payed attention to for a while until the other instructor is finished, and whatever the instructor had been telling the paintor (like, what brush to use, or what color to paint) gets forgotten.

The GraphicsDevice, hence, is a "LostDevice". So while you are having the other application drawing on an adapter, any device (recently created or not) for that videocard and adapter will be lost, until the other application frees the real device (videocard).

Only one GraphicsDevice can perform on an adapter at the same time.

As Jeff said, use the other adapter (monitor) when you create the other GraphicsDevice. The other option is to coordinate the action of both applications if you are looking forward to draw onto the same monitor. The OTHER option, is you make everything windowed, because when things are "windowed", the operative system owns the Device, meaning it will be the Operative System the one in charge of combining the drawing of the applications. (Its problem, not yours)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm wrong, because it would be pretty cool.  But I don't believe that the XNA APIs allow you to render onto two separately monitors at once using dual graphics devices.